# XPath Predicate Issue

Tags: xml, xpathnavigator

I've got an XPath expression with a predicate that selects
a person's name and ID from within a nested element, using
the XPathNavigator.Select method.

This works:

```
root/all_clients/client/client_name_and_ID[client_ID = 'xxx']
```

This also works:

```
root/all_clients/client[client_name_and_ID/client_ID = 'xxx']/client_name_and_ID
```

When I take the predicate to the next level, it does not work:

```
root/all_clients[client/client_name_and_ID/client_ID = 'xxx']/client/client_name_and_ID
```

I do not get any filtering, but the entire set.

Is this due to a limitation inherent within XPath, within ASP.NET,
or am I doing something stupid?

What follows is a snippet from the relevant XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///n:\Projects\XML\Medical\Example_01.xsd">

<all_clients>

    <client>
        <client_name_and_ID>
            <first_name>Fred</first_name>
            <middle_name>James</middle_name>
            <last_name>Bowman</last_name>
            <client_ID>1</client_ID>
        </client_name_and_ID>
    </client>

    <client>
        <client_name_and_ID>
            <first_name>Mark</first_name>
            <middle_name>David</middle_name>
            <last_name>Colder</last_name>
            <client_ID>2</client_ID>
        </client_name_and_ID>
    </client>

    <client>
        <client_name_and_ID>
            <first_name>Joe</first_name>
            <last_name>Lewis</last_name>
            <client_ID>3</client_ID>
        </client_name_and_ID>
    </client>

    <client>
        <client_name_and_ID>
            <first_name>Sam</first_name>
            <last_name>Plank</last_name>
            <client_ID>4</client_ID>
        </client_name_and_ID>
    </client>
</all_clients>

</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last query is matching an all_clients element that contains *any* matching client underneath it. It then selects clients under this all_clients without the filter applied, so it selects *all* of the client elements.

You should save the filter for the end of the XPath. First select down to the type of element you want, and then apply a filter to those elements. Try these XPaths:

```
<!-- Select client_ID element. -->
root/all_clients/client/client_name_and_ID/client_ID[. = 'xxx']

<!-- Select client_name_and_ID element. -->
root/all_clients/client/client_name_and_ID[client_ID = 'xxx']

<!-- Select client element. -->
root/all_clients/client[client_name_and_ID/client_ID = 'xxx']
```

Comment: I see now. Thanks John, for the response and the examples.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. All `client` nodes are children of the `all_clients` node. Therefore it will always qualify to the condition "all elements named `all_clients` having at least one match of a descendant `client/client_name_and_ID/client_ID = 'xxx'`" which is what you have coded.

Comment: Thanks Alain. I think I get it now, especially after reading the examples posted by John.